# ‘Permission denied’ while connecting to abstract unix socket

Tags: android, sockets, permissions

OS: Android L
Server: an native level system server, service through abstract socket.
Client: jni in normal 3rd APK
Get a 'permission denied' while using APK to connect the socket.
I thought **abstract socket has no permissions**!

And, the same code works when running in a adb shell, rooted shell.

The question is: **where is the permisson set**?

the code:

```
char *target_socket_name = "@mobilelogd"; 
int sock_id = 0; 
struct sockaddr_un sun;
int address_len;

sock_id = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (sock_id < 0) {
    LOG("in %s: Unable to create socket: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
    return -1;
} else {
    LOG("socket created!\n");       
}
memset(&sun, 0, sizeof(sun));
sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strncpy(sun.sun_path, target_socket_name, strlen(target_socket_name));
sun.sun_path[0] = 0;
address_len = offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sun_path) + strlen(target_socket_name);

if (connect(sock_id, (struct sockaddr *)&sun, address_len) == -1) 
{
    LOG("in %s: Connect to socket failed: (%d),%s\n", __func__, errno, strerror(errno));
    close(sock_id);
    return -1;
}
```

**--- EDIT 1 ---**: add some initialise code,and change '0' to 0. Same result.

Comment: There is no permission set for abstract sockets. First, try to change '0' to 0 in `memset(&sun, 0, sizeof(sun));` Than, how did you initialise `sock_id` and `target_socket_name`?

Comment: may be adding INTERNET permission in your app manifest will help you?

Comment: Did u tried the my suggestion?

Comment: the INTERNET permission is already in the manifest,sorry it's not the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the scoop it changed on L by a bug introduced..the bug fix is the pipeline:

https://android.googlesource.com/device/moto/shamu/+/b2db40f

Until than do java pipes or native pipes instead

Comment: Thanks, looks like SeLinux is the answer! After disable SEAndroid with `setenforce 0`, it works now. Though i can not find the excat place where the permssion being set.

Answer (score 0):

Since Android manipulated the Linux kernel and added [Paranoid networking](http://elinux.org/Android_Security#Paranoid_network-ing) to it, So you should add the following permission to your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> Android adds a "paranoid network" option to the Linux kernel, which restricts access to some networking features depending on the group of the calling process.

So, your app's `uid` (user id; each app is assigned an unique `uid` once it is installed) must be granted that permission in order to do networking tasks.

Comment: the INTERNET permission is already in the manifest,sorry it's not the answer